# Title ONLY Alignment and minitoc Question

Tags: latex

I want to do this in Latex
http://prntscr.com/nejl0x

But I cant make it work.

My code is the following

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\usepackage{minitoc} % for contents 
\chapterfont{\raggedleft}
\begin{document}
\dominitoc[n]


\chapter{Introduction}
    \minitoc
    \section{About}
    \label{sec:About}
    \section{Motivation}
    \label{sec:Motivation}
\end{document}
```

But It doesn't work.
Also I cannot understand how to use the \undotted and \nomtcpagenumbers for minitoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fasted way to remove the dotted lines is the `undotted` package option. To remove the page numbers, you can use `\mtcsetpagenumbers{minitoc}{off}`

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\usepackage[undotted]{minitoc}
\mtcsetpagenumbers{minitoc}{off}
\mtcsetoffset{minitoc}{-4em}

\chapterfont{\raggedleft}

\begin{document}

\dominitoc
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\minitoc

\section{About}
\label{sec:About}
\section{Motivation}
\label{sec:Motivation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And how am I putting the Chapter to the left and the Introduction to the right?

Comment: @Broxigar That are different questions unrelated to minitoc. I suggest to only ask one question per question.

Comment: Firstly no one said that this topic is about minitoc. The topic involves minitoc but thats it. Now I asked something very specific. How do I on A Report document align the Chapter part to one side (left) and the Chapter's title to the other (right) like in the print screen. If you don't know the answer just say it, don't hide behind the "ONe QuESTioan aT a  TiME pLZ". Oh and I've seen topics with >2 questions being asked. Just sayin.

Comment: @Broxigar Asking separate questions for unrelated problems won't cost you anything, but it would help future users with the same problems to find a solution. Right now users with the same problem will have a hard time to find it, well hidden behind a none descriptive title and buried among a unrelated questions.